# Is it possible to set different select2 parameters at different times?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

From playing around I can see that this code

```
$("#Selected3").select2({ minimumInputLength: 3 });
$("#Selected3").select2({ placeholder: "Show a placeholder" });
```

will show me the placeholder but remove the minimumInputLength parameters value.

Does anyone know a way please that this example could be modified so that the placeholder will be added without losing the minimum..Length value.

Any answers will need to allow for the possibility of the statements being in separate files, i.e. one on the page and another in a referenced .js file.

I am aware that this would be much easier if I set all the parameters at once, e.g.

```
$("#Selected3").select2({
        minimumInputLength: 3,
        placeholder: "Show a placeholder"
    });
```

but I am working within a framework which won't currently allow that.

EDIT: For anyone who is willing to give this a shot but doesn't know select2 the library comes from here [Select2 on GitHub](https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/wiki)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to adjust the options without re-initializing select2. You could store the options in a variable somewhere and then adjust this as necessary, but in order to take effect, the select2 control will need to be re-initialized:

```
var options = { minimumInputLength: 3 };

// initialize
$("#select3").select2(options);

// change options
options.placeholder="show a placeholder";

// need to reinitialize select2 for options to take effect
$("#select3").select2("destroy").select2(options);
```

or take a look at this jsfiddle and play arround with it: http://jsfiddle.net/JjV9m/2/

You can also change select2 defaults

```
$.fn.select2.defaults.placeholder = "New placeholder...";
```

Note that you will still need to reinitalize existing select2 instances, and that this will take effect for every instance created after the change.

Comment: Thanks for the response, this seems like it could have potential, I guess the follow up question to make it work across multiple files would be "How do you read the previously set options?"

Comment: @ReiMasuro You can create variables in a private namespace, as to not conflict with other variable names. For example, create the namespace: var mynamespace = {}; then you can create an options variable in that namespace like so: mynamespace.options = {  minimumInputLength: 3 };
If you want to capture the previous settings in a separate variable you can do this: var oldSettings = $.extend({}, mynamespace.options); then update mynamespace.options, the oldSettings will not change. Read more about how $.extend works @ http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/

Comment: Looks like that should cover it, thank you for all your help.